# Created an EBS volume from a snapshot, but can't mount it?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

`fdisk -l` shows the volume so it looks like it's attached but when I follow these steps

```
echo "/dev/xvdg /vol2 xfs noatime 0 0" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
sudo mkdir /vol2
sudo mount /vol2
```

I get the error

```
 mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/xvdg,
     missing codepage or helper program, or other error
     In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
     dmesg | tail  or so
```

When I check dmesg I see

```
XFS: Filesystem xvdg has duplicate UUID - can't mount
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 23):

Either mount without the UUID (short term solution):

```
mount -o nouuid DEVICE MOUNT_POINT
```

OR generate a new UUID for the device and then mount normally:

```
xfs_admin -U generate DEVICE
```

(First Google result by the way. [XFS Filesystem has duplicate UUID problem](https://linux-tips.com/t/xfs-filesystem-has-duplicate-uuid-problem/181))

Comment: The link does not exist anymore.